# How to play Minecraft online with some guys

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been playing MCPE for about 6 months alone. I want to know how I can play with some other guys in Survival mode. Do I need a server? If so, I have no idea how to create one.

Comment: Also, this isn't a forum where you can place requests. This is a question & answer site. Asking if someone could join your game is off-topic.

Comment: @Nolonar well.. so where is the forum i could place requests??

Comment: I don't know. Maybe try reddit?

Answer (score -2):

Hey dude i know how you feel minecraft can get really lonely without friends so if you ever find any friends then just

- Have them on the same server as you (wifi)
- Then go to the tab "Friends" (15.0+) and they should show up in green lettering
  Hopes this help if you need any other help with this just ask.